# Scroll Issue inside Relative layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-relativelayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have layout as below : 
Contains A main RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout contains Two SwipeToRefereshLayout. Issue is only First SwipeToRefereshLayout is Scrollable.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rltUserActivity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh_media_grid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/viewTop"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recFeedGrid"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh_newsfeed_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/viewTop"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lvFeed"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@color/transparant"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Here, In above code, when I put `swipe_to_refresh_media_grid` above the `swipe_to_refresh_newsfeed_list`, then only `swipe_to_refresh_media_grid` is scrollable and the issue is `swipe_to_refresh_newsfeed_list` is not scrollable. At a time any one of them is visible.

I am talking about scrolling of RecyclerView and ListView which is inside particular SwipeToRefereshLayout.

Issue : First Collection is scrollable in Relativelayout, Second one is not scrollable.

What might be the issue ?

Comment: Use `RecyclerView` for your `swipe_to_refresh_newsfeed_list` too. Why you used `ListView` where as you are using `RecyclerView` for `swipe_to_refresh_media_grid`.

Comment: Am Using recyclerview here for displaying media as a grid. Otherwise listview is okay.

Comment: Is the root is a `CoordinatorLayout`? Then it's good to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` and will scroll without any issues.

Comment: @AbidKhan If I put swipe_to_refresh_newsfeed_list above the swipe_to_refresh_media_grid then swipe_to_refresh_newsfeed_list is scrollable and swipe_to_refresh_media_grid is not scrollable first time.

Answer (score 0):

remove this and try

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Comment: What is "this" that should be removed? Why should one "try" the second string? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Hello, My layout is inside Bottomsheet, That's why am adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"